# Slide transition using CSS

Tags: css-transitions

I have a particular transition I'm trying to implement: there's basically three sections: a fixed-width vertical navigation bar on the left, a collapsible section next to that, and the remainder of the page. When you click an icon in the nav bar, the left panel toggles open/close. The transition should make the left panel "slide" under the nav bar.

So we simply animate the `left` property, right? Well..[no](http://jsbin.com/OWuzaDu/2/edit). The position is changed, but it still has the same width, so it's affecting the right side in the same way.

I also tried some other stuff, like animating the right side instead, but they ended up requiring the use of `calc()` in animations, which IE does not support.

Long story short, I got a [prototype](http://jsbin.com/ATiNaXoD/2/edit) working. The catch is that it depends on the `vw` unit. From caniuse.com and my testing in our supported browsers (basically, IE10+, recent versions of Chrome and Safari), it appears to work fine, and it's apparently in Candidate Reccommendation status, but I'm a little hesistant to rely on something that's so new for a production site.

So basically, I have a couple of questions:

- Is there a simpler way to do this (I feel like there should be)? One that's supported on IE10+?
- Are viewport units stable enough that they're okay to put into production (assuming we don't need the `vmax` unit, or vertical units, or use them in `calc()` statements)?

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery?

Comment: I'd like to stay away from JS for transitions as much as possible. If there's absolutely no other way, I'll bite the bullet, but I'd like to exhaust all CSS-only options first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [the checkbox hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) you don't need any javascript, viewport units, or `calc` at all! It requires that you change your markup and CSS a little to compensate

```
<!-- Changed HTML -->
<!-- The only thing you need to change is to surround the `ul` in a label and 
     add a corresponding input for it -->
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1" />
<label for="toggle-1">
  <ul class="chart-tabs">
    <li>Chart</li>
    <li>Tabs</li>
  </ul>
</label>

/* Changed CSS */
.chart-tabs {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.left-content {
  width: 33%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  z-index: 1;

  .section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: orange;
  }
}

/* CSS to add */
label[for='toggle-1'] {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 54px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}    
#toggle-1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}    
#toggle-1:checked ~ .left-content { margin-left:-33%; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ISOrofi/2/edit)

My method allows `%` to be used instead of `vw`, but you could use viewport units depending on how far back you want to reach. [All current major browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)

Comment: It's still using viewport units, though. My question was not how to trigger the change, but how to make the content slide in/out.

Comment: @TurnerHayes You can change my demo to use px and it works the same, changed to suit!

Comment: I could use absolute widths, yes, but that doesn't work well over multiple resolutions; at width X, it'll look fine, but at width X/2, for instance, it'll be way too big (and at widtth 2X, way too small). I want it to have a width relative to the viewport width. Which I can do with the parent `.left-content` container, since it's a child of an element that takes up the full viewport width, but its child `.section` is relative to the container, not the full viewport width.

Comment: And regarding viewport width support, I see that "officially", they are supported in current browsers, but there's support, and then there's "support"--I was more wondering whether anyone had any experiential knowledge of issues with viewport units.

Comment: @TurnerHayes Updated to use percents

Comment: Because, as I mentioned, the `.section` element's percentage is relative to its parent `.left-content`'s width, not the full viewport. So when I animate the width of `.left-content` down to 0, the `.section` width will also go to 0, causing it to "squish", rather than slide.

Comment: @TurnerHayes That's why you use a negative left margin like my updated demo instead (:

Comment: margin-left, of course! Why didn't I think of that? Thank you, I'm marking this as the answer.